# In Terraform what does the encapsulation "#{variableName}" syntax mean?

Tags: terraform, octopus-deploy

I am familiar with "${}" syntax, but can't find any reference to "#{}" in the Terraform docs, yet I see it in this example: [Terraform v0.12 Multi-line String EOF shell-style "here doc" syntax not been interpreted as before with v0.11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57379491/terraform-v0-12-multi-line-string-eof-shell-style-here-doc-syntax-not-been-int)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a Terraform thing, it's an [Octopus Deploy](https://octopus.com/) thing instead.

It's used for [variable substitution](https://octopus.com/docs/deployment-process/configuration-features/substitute-variables-in-files) so that you can define a variable in Octopus Deploy and have that injected into your Terraform before it runs the relevant Terraform commands.

The Octopus docs for [deploying with Terraform](https://octopus.com/docs/deployment-examples/terraform-deployments/apply-terraform#variable-replacements) go into further detail and give the following example:

```
provider "aws" { }

resource "aws_instance" "example" {
  ami           = "#{AMI}"
  instance_type = "m3.medium"
  tags {
    Name = "My EC2 Instance"
  }
}
```

where `#{AMI}` would be replaced by the AMI id that Octopus has configured in the `AMI` variable.

Comment: Thanks it was driving me insane!